# Prometheus monitoring: Show maximum number of nodes allowed in a node group (AWS EKS)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks

i'm trying to show in grafana the max number of nodes that is set in the node group, to contrast with current number of nodes (and eventually make an alert)

What i have is current number of nodes:

```
sum(up{instance=~".*.myregion.compute.internal", eks_amazonaws_com_nodegroup="mygroup"})
```

Any tips? Thanks!

I tried different queries, with no result. I have no idea what query would work here.

Answer (score 0):

I think (!?) the way to do this is to use `max_over_time`.

You'll need to specify the time period (e.g. `[1w]`) over which you want to determine the max value.

Then you can divide current/total to get a ratio:

```
sum
  without(instance,eks_amazonaws_com_nodegroup) 
  (up{
    instance=~".*.myregion.compute.internal", 
    eks_amazonaws_com_nodegroup="mygroup"
  })
/
sum
  without(instance,eks_amazonaws_com_nodegroup) 
  (max_over_time(
    up{
      instance=~".*.myregion.compute.internal", 
      eks_amazonaws_com_nodegroup="mygroup"
    }[1w]
  ))
```